# Show a function is a diffeomorphism

Tags: functions, differential-geometry, proof-writing

Let $T^2$ = {($x, y, z$) $\in \Bbb{R}^3$ | $x^2 + y^2 + z^2 = 1$)}.

Show that the function $A$: $S^2 \to S^2$ : ($x, y, z$) $\mapsto$ ($-x, -y, -z$) is a diffeomorphism.

A general definition of a diffeomorphism is that it is a smooth, differentiable, invertible map between manifolds. But what exactly does that mean and how do I use this definition to answer the question above?

Answer (score 1):

The map $A$ is obviously differentiable, because its scalar components $x,y,z$ are.
 Since $A\circ A=Id_{S^2}$, $A$ is  bijective and its inverse is $A^{-1}=A$ itself, hence the inverse  is differentiable and thus $A$ is a diffeomorphism.

**NB** I have written this answer in order to show that a solution can be both  rigorous and concise.

Comment: As far as I know to check differentiability for a map between manifolds you have to do it by local charts (at least at this basic level). Since we're dealing with a map between manifolds is your argument for differentiability alright?

Comment: @QWERTZ Yes, my argument for differentiability is alright.  It easily follows from the definitions  that if you have a differentiable map $f:X\to Y$ between completely arbitrary differential manifolds and if $X'\subset X, Y'\subset Y$ are completely arbitrary submanifolds such that $f(X')\subset Y'$, then the  restricted map $f\vert X':X'\to Y'$ is differentiable.